# Eloquent eager load, select count and sum

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My goal is to retrieve 'events' and 'eventtypes', count the number of 'events' on each day (groupby days) and also get the total sum of 'eventtypes.price' on each of those days. I'm having a problem accessing the eventtype table.

Event table

```
id
event_start
```

Eventtype table

```
id
price
```

Query (this query works)

```
    $events = Event::with('eventtype')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(events.event_start) as date'), DB::raw('count(*) as eventcount'))
    ->where('events.event_start', '>=', $rangestart)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Query (this query return error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'eventtypes.price' in 'field list')

```
    $events = Event::with('eventtype')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(events.event_start) as date'), DB::raw('count(*) as eventcount'), DB::raw('sum(eventtypes.price) as sumtotal'))
    ->where('events.event_start', '>=', $rangestart)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Not sure why would eventtypes.price be unknown, it's clearly defined in my Model, and I use it else where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join `eventtypes`

You should add smth like that to your query.

```
->join('eventtypes', 'event.type_id', '=', 'eventtypes.id')
```

I think you miss understand that `with` it's an eager loading, and this relation does not accessible in the query.

Comment: ahhhhhh, I thought that `with` was an instant `join`. Super, thanks, it works!